# How to print the Data part of Linkedlist

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Basically I want to print the data part of the Linked list which is basically an Integer pointer and I am assigning it an array at the time of creation, I want to print all the values of it how to do so ???
Thank you.
**Here is my code**
    using namespace std;

```
struct Node{
    Node *next;
    int *data;
};
class DataLine{
    private:
      Node *first;
    public:
      DataLine(){
          first=NULL;
  }
    void create_list(){
        Node *temp=new Node;
        int i=2;
        int dat[5]={12,13,14,13,16};
        temp->data=dat;
        temp->next=NULL;
        if(first==NULL){
            //cout<<"hello 1"<<endl;
            first=temp;

        }
        else{
            Node *curr=first;    //We are now doing trevercing so we are assigning the first to the node because we donot want to move the first bacuse link break if we move the first
            while(curr->next!=NULL) //searching end of list
            {   
                curr=curr->next; //Moving to the next node
            }
            curr->next=temp; //insert node

            temp=NULL;        //Making the temp enpty to use it for the new purpose
            //delete temp;
        }
    }
    void print_list()
        {
            Node *prnt=first;  //We are now again want trevercing so we agin run the node by the new node
            while(prnt!=NULL)  //Checking the loop will run till it get the null in the node means its address part and data part both are nUll
            {
                for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
                cout<<"         ***** The "<<" node is "<<*(prnt->data+i)<<endl; //Printing the data
                prnt=prnt->next;           //Moving to the next node
            }

        }
};
int main(){
DataLine dl;
dl.create_list();
    dl.print_list();
_getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: are you sure your create_list works? I dont think so. Exactly what are you trying to achieve in create_list(). Because you are assigning base address of array to only one node. So its going to be one node only, i.e. first.

Comment: `dat` is a local variable. It goes out of scope and is destroyed as soon as `create_list` returns, at which point `first->data` becomes a dangling pointer. You don't actually have any valid data to print.

Comment: Create is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of your `void print_list(void)` is correct but you can make it much cleaner, note however I changed your output to print a single node per line (change that back if you want).  The structure of a `for` loop seems, to me, perfect for linked lists and keeps the linked list code our of the body of the loop.

```
void print_list(void) const
{
    for (Node* p = first; p != NULL; p = p->next)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Node::unLength; ++i) std::cout << p->data[i] << ", ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

However, as pointed out in some of the comments, there are other problems in your create list code.  The way I would suggest to fix these (for this program) would be to redefine your structure to always hold a fixed number of integers.

```
struct Node
{
    enum { unLength = 5 };
    Node* next;
    int data[unLength];
};
```

I have also added here a constant for the length of the array, since its bad practice to have magic numbers floating around your code, what happens if you mistype one of them?

Now in your `void create_list()` you can go:

```
void create_list()
{
    Node* temp = new Node;

    // Set the next node of temp
    temp->next = NULL;

    // Add some data to temp (we can't just assign the data pointer in C/C++)
    int data[Node::unLength] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    for (int i = 0; i < Node::unLength; ++i) temp->data[i] = data[i];

    Node *p = first;
    while (p != NULL) p = p->next;
    p->next = temp;
}
```

There is no point setting `temp` to `NULL` since temp is deleted straight after the function returns.  In your previous code you set the pointer in `Node` to `data` (`temp->data=dat;`, this doesn't work either since `dat` was deleted as soon as the function returned, you need to instead allocate memory and copy the values from `dat` which is what the `for` loop in the above code does.

For you class constructor (and destructor) I would suggest:

```
class DataLine
{
private:
    Node* first;

public:
    DataLine(void) : first(NULL) {}
    ~DataLine(void)
    {
        while (first != NULL)
        {
            Node *temp = first->next;
            delete first;
            first = temp;
        }
    }
```

You had the right idea, but there are a few subtle things about C/C++ that aren't obvious in higher level languages, such as copying arrays and the scope of variables.

If you are using C++ however, I would really suggest not worrying about linked lists, just create a `std::vector`, in C++ 11 something like the following might work (untested):

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::vector< std::array<int, 5> > myData;
    myData.push_back({0, 1, 2, 3, 4});
    myData.push_back({0, 1, 2, 3, 4});
    myData.push_back({0, 1, 2, 3, 4});

    for (const auto& i : myData)
    {
        for (int j : i) std::cout << j << ", ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```